# Speed up stitching of 2 images?

Tags: opencv, imaging, vision, computer-vision

I am working with 2 fly cameras and trying to stitch them together.
I am working with OpenCV and C++ here.

Since I am trying to cover large region using both cameras (and to contour detection later on), I am wondering if there's a fast way to stitch both images from both cameras together ?

Currently here's what I am doing:

1. Removing each camera's image with previously stored background image (to speed up contour detection later on)
2. Un-distort each image using cvRemap function
3. And finally to set the ROI of the images for stitching them together.

My question is, is it possible to speed this up even more ? Since currently these steps take around 60ms, and with additional functionality it slows down to 0.1 second.

Have I been using the slower functions of OpenCV ? Or are there any tricks to gain more speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the latest OpenCV snapshot from [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser) and try the stitching module implemented here. They have been working on stitching performance lately, so it's possible to get some good improvements.

By the way, what step takes the most? Did you profile your app? Take a look at the profile results, and you'll be able to understand exactly where to optimize, and maybe how to do it.

Comment: For now just by measuring elapsed time for each functions, cvAbsDiff and cvRemap both takes around 10 - 12ms each. And since it's for 2 cameras, they take around 60ms plus the setImageROI which takes around 4 - 5 ms each.

Comment: what you can do (if it suits your requirements) is to resize your input video, to make it smaller. Apart from that, it's hard to guess what to do..